# How to create view to show number of items from diffrenet items tables using the user id by SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables that saves datasets, projects, integrations links. the three tables using the user id to link the items with the logged in user as below image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FfMe.png)

I want to create view to show me the number of those items related to the user id like the following:

| user id | datasets | projects | integrations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 5 | 3 |

I want to create SQL to use it for creating view that show these results.

Comment: Please show some effort and post what you have so far. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I suggest you start with the `Users` table and do three `LEFT JOIN`s to the other three tables, then use a `GROUP BY` clause and `COUNT` expressions to calculate your totals

Comment: @RobEyre You would need three `GROUP BY`s in subqueries otherwise you would get a cartesian product of all tables.

Comment: Also, please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution is to use simple SQL sentence to select logged-in user and combine with select sentence from each table when user id are matched to give the required results.

```
select u.id, 
   (select count(md.id) from my_datasets md where md.user_id = u.id) datasets,
   (select count(ps.id) from projects ps where ps.user_id = u.id) projects,
   (select count(mp.model_id) from model_profile mp where mp.user_id = u.id) models from User u
```

When i used left join or join operators i was getting duplicate results